# PHP Search database and directory structure and match together

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with page_name column which lists all my pages like:

```
directory1/test1.php
directory2/test_page.php
directory3/sub_dir/page5.php
```

etc.. so it lists the page name and the directory its in

how can i match this list with my directory structure and display all the pages that are not listed in my database table?

so i want to display the files and directories like this:

*dir1/file1.php
dir1/file2.php
dir2/file1.php
dir3/file1.phpdir3/file2.php*

but only to display if they are not in the database. for example, is `dir1/file.php` is in the table it will not display on the list

Comment: plz elaborate 'display all the pages' in your question, as it sounds like to hide other page access or just display their paths !

Comment: see my edit for more info

Answer (score 1):

You can get the filenames of a specific directory using PHP's built-in directory functions:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php

You would, for each file, check if it exists in your database and if not, you print that file.

Answer (score 0):

first you may need 'Recursive directory travering', I am posting below the code I found,

```
$rootpath = '.';
$fileinfos = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootpath)
);
foreach($fileinfos as $pathname => $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isFile()) continue;
    var_dump($pathname);
}
```

that displays like:

```
string(11) ".\.htaccess"
string(33) ".\dom\xml-attacks\attacks-xml.php"
string(38) ".\dom\xml-attacks\billion-laughs-2.xml"
string(36) ".\dom\xml-attacks\billion-laughs.xml"
```

and so on,

now roughly you can use,

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE $pathname NOT IN ('your_table')';
```

just below foreach for your task.

Comment: that seems to work, how can i add exceptions. so how can i exclude a directory?

Comment: how does this exclude directories?

Comment: where is the $total_rows variable coming from? do i use both parts of your above code together?

Comment: firstly dont just copy the code, its in raw form !
and secondly for $total_rows you can use COUNT(*).

Comment: i was only asking, you haven't really explained the second part of your answer very well